# Google maps add multiple markers and info windows for each one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have my code like this:

```
function algolia_search(position) {
  clearOverlays();
var APPLICATION_ID = 'PSH...VAKL';
var SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY = '2eb...efa8';
var INDEX_NAME = 'entities';
var PARAMS = { hitsPerPage: 150 };
// Client + Helper initialization
var algolia = algoliasearch(APPLICATION_ID, SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY);
var algoliaHelper = algoliasearchHelper(algolia, INDEX_NAME, PARAMS);
// Map initialization
algoliaHelper.on('result', function(content) {
    renderHits(content);
  var i;
  // Add the markers to the map
  for (i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
    var hit = content.hits[i];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: hit.name
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: hit._geoloc.lat, lng: hit._geoloc.lng},
      map: map,
      label: hit.name,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      index: i
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    addListenerOnPoint(marker);
    markers.push(marker);
    infos.push(infowindow);
  }
});
function renderHits(content) {
  $('#container').html(JSON.stringify(content, null, 2));
}
  algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', 200);
  algoliaHelper.search();
}
```

Now the markers works absolutely fine, however the info windows doesn't. No matter which marker I click, it shows me an info windows from one marker, however I don't exactly know how to solve it.

Comment: Just a note that you should take care about posting API keys on public forums

Comment: that's not the real api key, I have added random characters but thanks

Comment: Cool, thought I'd edit your question just in case :)

Comment: Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation of the problem

The infowindow shows you data  from one markerbecause when you click on them they call:

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

At the point they are clicked, waht do you think the values for `infowindow`,`map` and `marker` are respectively?

Your assumption is that they will hold the values that you set ***as the for loop is running***.

What is happening is that the ***for loop has finished running completely*** by the time you click on the the marker.  The values of `infowindow` and `marker` will happen to be set to the last value of the for loop.

---

#### Suggested solution(s)

The solution for this is to find a way to encapsulate the data for each iteration of the loop that will persist when the listener is called.

Two ways to do this are to use the ES6 block scoped `let` instead of `var` OR use n IIFE (Immediate Invoked Function Expression) to encapsulate the state of the `infowindow` and `marker` for each step of the loop.

> **Using `let`:**
>
> ```
> for(i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
>     // rest of code above --^
>
>     let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: hit.name});
>
>     let marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
>
>     marker.addListener('click', function() {
>       infowindow.open(map, marker);
>     });
>
>     // rest of code below --v
> }
> ```
>
> The above works because what effectively happens is that a new
>   variable is created for each `infowindow` and `marker` variable for
>   *each* iteration, ***almost like creating a new vairable name for each iteration***(`marker0`, `marker1`, etc)

---

> **Using an IIFE:**
>
> ```
> for(i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
>     // rest of code above --^
>
>     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: hit.name});
>
>     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
>
>     function(inf, mar){
>       marker.addListener('click', function() {
>         inf.open(map, mar);
>       })(infowindow, marker);
>     }
>     // rest of code below --v    
> }
> ```

Comment: how would I do an closure?

Comment: In this case it's more accurate to call it an IIFE, where you pass the current iteration values for `infowindow` and `marker` to a function defintion that sets the listener

Comment: IIFE method, seems not to work. I am not getting anyerrors

Comment: Can you create an example in jsbin or codepen for me to look at?

Comment: I can't really because I am using algolia and I don't think codepen will work from that